# Prove that the following series is convergent at $z=0$ & divergent at $z=b$

Tags: complex-analysis

> Prove that the power series $\displaystyle \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_n(z-a)^n$ , $a\not =0$ can converge at $z=0$ and diverges at $z=b$ whenever $|b-a|<|a|$.

I want to show that radius of convergent at $z=b$ is $0$ to show the divergence, but I am unable to show it.  Please help me.

Comment: What have you done? What are your thoughts at least?

Comment: $b = a$ satisfies $0 = \lvert b - a \rvert < \lvert a \rvert$ yet the series converges at $z = b = a$...